# when i run the code it says "not acceptable 406 " how can i fix it?

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

and i searched through IBM cloud and in their error handling they said that the server does not support this type of files

```
from ibm_watson import PersonalityInsightsV3
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator
authenticator = IAMAuthenticator('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
personality_insights = PersonalityInsightsV3(
       version='2019-10-12',
authenticator=authenticator)
personality_insights.set_service_url('https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api')
profile_text = open("personality.txt").read()
profile = personality_insights.profile(profile_text,"text/plain").get_result()
needs = profile["needs"]
values = profile["values"]
personality = profile["personality"]
def print_traits(traits_category_name, traits):
  print(traits_category_name + ":")
for trait in traits:
  print(trait["name"] + ": {:.3f}%".format(
trait["percentile"] * 100))
print("\n")
print_traits("Needs", needs)
print_traits("Values", values)
print_traits("Personality", personality)
```

[this is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFlow.png)

[and this the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkBlA.png)

Comment: Hello, you should provide the actual source code, not a picture of it.

Comment: i edited the post and i submitted the source code

Comment: It would help if the response was part of the question too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me start by telling you that by sharing your credential key in your question you have compromised it, and you should revoke as soon as you can.

The reason you are getting a HTTP 406, is because you have provided an invalid `accept` type of `text/plain`. If you take a look at the Python SDK API documentation for the service - https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/personality-insights?code=python#get-profile - you will see that the second parameter is `accept` and the only valid types are `application/json` and `text/csv`.

I think you were actually trying to set `content_type`, so you need to your service invocation to :

```py
profile = personality_insights.profile(profile_text, accept='application/json', content_type='text/plain').get_result()
```

Comment: first of all thank for telling to hide credentials second i converted the txt file to json and the same error appears

Comment: Did you read my answer? I didn't say to convert the txt file to json. I said to change the code to specify content_type as `text/plain`. If you are going to submit `application/json` as your content_type then your content needs to look something like: https://watson-developer-cloud.github.io/doc-tutorial-downloads/personality-insights/reference/profile.json